# the trait `futures::Stream` is not implemented for my type

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, closures

I am creating an update system. It create patch, between 2 binaries files, compress patches and binaries and start a webserver.

I need to call async fn from closure.
So the closure need to be async to use `await` fn

I do

```
let repair_stream = future::lazy(move |_| async {
        let mut failures = {
            let state = &mut *shared_state_r.borrow_mut();
            state.previous_failures = mem::take(&mut state.failures);
            state.previous_failures.clone()
        };
        if !failures.is_empty() {
            failures.sort();
            global_progression_r.lock().await.stage = UpdateStage::FindingRepairPath; // note the use of await
            Either::Left(
                update_internal(
                    update_options_r,
                    file_manager_r,
                    global_progression_r,
                    State::New, //< force to repair from no starting revision
                    shared_state_r,
                    repository,
                    goal_version_r,
                    UpdateFilter { failures },
                    UpdateStage::Repairing,
                )
                .try_flatten_stream(),
            )
        } else {
            // nothing to repair, everything went well
            Either::Right(stream::empty())
        }
    })
    .flatten_stream();
```

But get

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl futures::Future<Output = futures::future::Either<TryFlattenStream<impl futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<impl futures::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<SharedUpdateProgress, UpdateError>> + '_, UpdateError>>>, futures::stream::Empty<_>>>: futures::Stream` is not satisfied
   --> lib/src/workspace/updater.rs:342:25
    |
342 |       let repair_stream = future::lazy(move |_| async {
    |  _________________________^
343 | |         let mut failures = {
344 | |             let state = &mut *shared_state_r.borrow_mut();
345 | |             state.previous_failures = mem::take(&mut state.failures);
...   |
368 | |         }
369 | |     })
    | |______^ the trait `futures::Stream` is not implemented for `impl futures::Future<Output = futures::future::Either<TryFlattenStream<impl futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<impl futures::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<SharedUpdateProgress, UpdateError>> + '_, UpdateError>>>, futures::stream::Empty<_>>>`
370 |       .flatten_stream();
    |        -------------- required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `futures::Stream`:
              &mut S
              Abortable<St>
              ApplyStream
              AssertUnwindSafe<S>
              Box<S>
              Buffer<S, Item>
              BufferUnordered<St>
              Buffered<St>
            and 84 others
note: required by a bound in `flatten_stream`
   --> /home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.25/src/future/future/mod.rs:343:23
    |
343 |         Self::Output: Stream,
    |                       ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `flatten_stream`
```

lock fn returns `tokio::sync::MutexGuard`

full source: https://github.com/Ludea/speedupdate-rs/blob/master/lib/src/workspace/updater.rs#L342

I don't inderstand the issue and dont know how to fix it

Comment: The issue is you're calling `flatten_stream` on something that's not a stream. Can you maybe explain a little what this code is trying to accomplish? You can find more tips on how to improve your post in [ask].

Comment: Generally you should [edit] your post rather than answering in comments, also the link to the full source isn't "explain(ing) a little what this code is trying to do", put a short paragraph bofore you throw your code at us, that way we don't have to guess. The code be it the snippet or the full thing isn't doing that since it's not valid code.

Comment: First post updated !

Comment: `Future` is not a `Stream` and neither is `Either` why do you try to call `flatten_stream` in the last line anyways, it seems to me any stream you get in both of the cases is "flat" in the first place‽

Comment: Before the closure was not async, the closure returns a Lazy. I just had sync to closure